# How to order tabs in tab panel if tabs are added dynamically?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a `tabpanel` in my view with only one tab in it. Later when other data is loaded I add those tabs to this `tabpanel` but that way tabs are rendered in the order I have added. I want to show new tabs before existing tab but it always append tab after it, is there a way to do something like `addBefore` using which I can control position of tabs?

Here is my tabpanel:

```
{
    xtype           : 'tabpanel',
    flex            : 1,
    id          : 'featurePanel',
    tabBarPosition  : 'top',
    height          : '100%',
    ui              : 'maintabbar',
    tabBar          : { 
        layout : { 
            pack    : 'center' 
        } 
    },
    items   : [{
        title   : 'Tab 1',
        items   : [{
            xtype   : 'panel',
            id  : 'tab1Id'
        }]
    }]
}
```

Here is how I am adding new panels:

```
var featureList = Ext.create('MyTabApp.view.FeaturedList', {
        id      : "tab2Id"
    });
    var featurePanel = Ext.getCmp("featurePanel");
    featurePanel.add({
        title   : 'Tab 2',
        items   : [{
            xtype   : 'panel',
            items   : [featureList]
        }]
    });
```

I want this new tab(Tab 2) to appear before 'tab 1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tabpanel's add method will always add new tab at the end. So if you want to add new tab at some different position,  you have to use [insert](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-insert) method. With this method you can set the position for new tab being added.

With your code it can be like -

```
var featureList = Ext.create('MyTabApp.view.FeaturedList', {
    id      : "tab2Id"
});
var featurePanel = Ext.getCmp("featurePanel");
featurePanel.insert(0,{
    title   : 'Tab 2',
    items   : [{
        xtype   : 'panel',
        items   : [featureList]
    }]
});
```

This will add new tab at first position. If you are adding more than one tab, you can set counter and add new tabs accordingly.